# Texstudio Environment frontmatter undefined

Tags: front-matter

I am using TEXstudio. I am getting the following error

Environment frontmatter undefined. \begin{frontmatter}

Comment: Which document class do you use?

Comment: May be you should try `\frontmatter`!

Comment: Environment definitions are not related with any editor, even TeXstudio.

Comment: I am using article document class

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the KoMa-Skript-class `scrbook` `frontmatter` is not an environment.

Like `\mainmatter` and `\backmatter` it is a command, you can think of it as a button, that activates the correct settings for everything that follows.

A small example would look like this:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{example.bib}


\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{foo}
Bla
\cite{something}
\chapter{bar}

\appendix

\chapter{first chapter of appendix}

\backmatter
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```